# How to find reason for network problems

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

In our company network we experience severe lan problems. Every now and then, applications that need a stable connection to the database server crash with a "lost connection error". The clients run on Windows 10 connected to a PDC running on Windows Server 2012-R2, which also hosts the databases.

However, the problem occurs only in certain time intervals without any specific pattern. There are days when the problems occur every 30 seconds, followed by weeks of stable running.

I know how unspecific this description is, but I'm running out of ideas on where to go from here. Hence I would be gratefull for any starting point on where to look.

Comment: Monitor your network. Record traffic, loss rates etc. and then try to correlate this with the outage and with other things going on in your network.

Comment: Lost connection error (MySQL?) does not necessarily mean you have a network problem.

Comment: You are right, it is a problem with the certificate. Thanks for the hints

Comment: Well, there was a problem with the certificates, but it did not solve the problem. Using Microsoft Network Monitor, I see a lot of ARP Request from the client to the default Gateway and the DC in the moment, the connection breaks. Where would I go from here?